# Input field in the AngularJS Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS, I am trying to get the user input from the text box and use the input to Query an end point and populate the text box under it.Below is the UI

[image]

So in my

Below is the .html code for the UI

```
        <div hidden id="userData">
            <label style="font-size: medium">Enter Input *</label>
            <input name="userData" class="form-control" ng-model="request.userData">
           <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <button type="button" class='btn btn-success' ng-click="queryData()">Query</button>
            </div>
            <input name="userName" class="form-control" ng-model="request.userName">
            <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
            </div>
```

In the Controller I am trying to get the userData and use them in Odata end point as a Query parameter

```
    $scope.queryData = function () {

        var sList = getAppData.getCData(`STR?Bar eq '${$scope.request.userData}'`, `Basic ${$scope.key}`)
       ........             
            };
```

Above code doesnot return any data to sList so tried to store the user input in to the variable like below and used like

```
   $scope.queryData = function () {
        var userEntered = ${$scope.request.userData };
        var strainsList = getAppData.getCData(`STR?Bar eq '`+userEntered+`'`, `Basic ${$scope.key}`)
       ........             
            };
```

The above code doesnot work in the debug more.

When try to hard code like below works

```
var sList = getAppData.getCData(`STR?Bar eq '1234'`, `Basic ${$scope.key}`)
```

How to get the user Input (userData) in to the Button function.

Comment: i believe there's something wrong with the way you're passing data to your  `service`  `getCData`

Comment: Do you have `request` object initialized?

Comment: @manish when I hard code it works fine. Can you tell me how can I store in varaiable the user input?

Comment: also if your service is `async` where is the `callback` ?

Comment: okay, could you show me the hardcoded one?

Comment: @manish `(`STR?Bar eq '1234'`, `Basic ${$scope.key}`)`

Answer (score -1):

> on the basis of your comment about the `hard-coded` data, following should work.

when is confusion always bifurcate your code for readability, use `\` as escape sequence

```
var firstParam = `STR?Bar eq \'${$scope.request.userData}\'`;
var secondParam = `Basic ${$scope.key}`;
var sList = getAppData.getCData(firstParam, secondParam);
```